# How can I filter my array of numbers in Matlab/Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a very trivial example where I'm trying to filter by matching a String:

```
A = [0:1:999];
B = A(int2str(A) == '999');
```

This

```
A(A > 990);
```

works

This

```
int2str(5) == '5'
```

also works

I just can't figure out why I cannot put the two together. I get an error about nonconformant arguments.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't convert string '999' to a value?

Answer (score 1):

`int2str(A)` produces a very long `char` array (of size `1 x 4996`) containing the string representations of all those numbers (including spacing) appended together end to end.

```
int2str(A) == '999'
```

So, in the statement above, you're trying to compare a matrix of size `1 x 4996` with another of size `1 x 3`. This, of course, fails as the two either need to be of the same size, or at least one needs to be a scalar, in which case scalar expansion rules apply.

```
A(A > 990);
```

The above works because of logical indexing rules, the result will be the elements from the indices of `A` for which that condition holds true.

```
int2str(5) == '5'
```

This only works because the result of the `int2str` call is a `1 x 1` matrix (`'5'`) and you're comparing it to another matrix of the same size. Try `int2str(555) == '55'` and it'll fail with the same error as above.

I'm not sure what result you expected from the original statements, but maybe you're looking for this:

```
A = [0:1:999];
B = int2str(A(A == 999))  % outputs '999'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the `int2str()` conversion is what you are looking for. (Also, why do you need to convert numbers to strings and then carry out a char comparison?)

Suppose you have a simpler case:

```
A    = 1:3;
strA = int2str(A)
strA =
1  2  3
```

Note that this is a 1x7 char array. Thus, comparing it against a scalar char:

```
strA == '2'
ans =
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

Now, you might wanna transpose `A` and carry out the comparison:

```
int2str(A')=='2'
ans =
     0
     1
     0
```

however, this approach will not work if the number of digits of each number is not the same because lower numbers will be padded with spaces (try creating `A = 1:10` and comparing against `'2'`).

Then, create a cell array of string without whitespaces and use [`strcmp()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html):

```
csA = arrayfun(@int2str,A','un',0)
csA = 
    '1'
    '2'
    '3'

strcmp('2',csA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be much faster, and correct to turn the string into a number, than the other way around. Try

```
B = A(A == str2double ('999'));
```